# How to make DC motor's RPM come to its maximum value (analog 255) SLOWLY

Tags: c++, arduino

It is a homework and I have completely NO idea, my teacher says you need just `while`, `analogWrite` and a counter. I have a DC motor, a transistor and a 9V battery.

I know my code does NOTHING, but just as example.

```cpp
int analogPin = 3;
int count = 0;
void setup()
{
   pinMode(analogPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() { 
   while(count<30){
     analogWrite(analogPin , 255);
     delay(20000);
     count++;
   }
}
```

Comment: You probably should increase the step value step by step, and not write at once?

Comment: "slowly" means that you should *ramp* the value from the minimum to maximum in some smooth continuous fashion over time.

Comment: Something like this?: `while (rpm != 255) { analogWrite(... rpm); delay(1000); rpm++; }`? Why is count even needed here? Your code instantly ramps it to 255, and then.. what? waits for 20 seconds before doing the same thing again, 30 times, effectively a total of 10 minutes of doing nothing.

Comment: 255 is the speed

Comment: You don't need a `while()` - the Arduino framework calls `loop()` repeatedly - it already _is_ a loop.  Apart from that, your teacher presumably intended you to write the counter value to the analogue output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use counter value as your analogue output value:

```
void loop() 
{ 
    if( count < 256 )
    {
        analogWrite( analogPin, count ) ;
        delay( 20000 );
        count++ ;
    }
}
```

Note that you do not need a `while` loop; the Arduino framework already calls `loop()` iteratively (the clue is in the name).  However if your teacher thinks you need one and is expecting one, you may need to use one just for the marks. Alternatively discuss it with your teacher, and explain why it is unnecessary

In fact the delay too is arguably bad practice - it is unhelpful in applications where the `loop()` must do other things while controlling the motor.  The following allows other code to run whilst controlling the motor:

```
unsigned long delay_start = 0 ;

void loop() 
{ 
    if( count < 256 &&
        millis() - delay_start >= 20000ul )
    {
        analogWrite( analogPin, count ) ;
        count++ ;
        delay_start = millis() ;
    }

    // Do other stuff here
}
```

Because the `loop()` now never blocks on the `delay()` function, you can have code that does other things such as read switch inputs and it can react to them instantly, whereas as in your solution, such inputs could be ignored for up-to 20 seconds!

A typical DC motor will not start moving at very low values - you may want to start `count` somewhat higher than zero to account for the "dead-band".  Analogue signals are also generally a poor way to drive a DC motor and varying speed; a PWM is generally a more efficient method, and will allow the motor to run at lower speeds.  With an analogue signal at low levels (lower than for PWM), your motor will not move and will just get warm and drain your battery.

For test purposes, reduce the delay time;  you don't want to sit there for an hour and 25 minutes just to find the code does not work!  Set it to say 500ms, then start it, time how long it takes before the motor starts to move.  If that is say 30 seconds, then yu know the motor starts to move when `count` is about 60; in which case that is a better starting value that zero.  Then you can increase your delay back to 20 seconds if you wish - though a DC power supply might be better than a battery - I'm not sure it will last that long.